# Enforce Type variable to be of a specific base class type

Tags: c#, base-class

Having the following code:

```
class Car{}
class WV : Car{}
class BMW: Car{}
class Bike{}
class Yamaha : Bike {}
class KTM : Bike{}

void DoSomething(<some other parameters>, Type targetType){}

//I call DoSomething with:
service.DoSomething(...., typeof(BMW));
```

Is there any way to enforce the `targetype` to be only for the base class `Car` **while the programmer is writing the code**?

During the execution is easy to check, but I want to enforce the expected base class that we want.

I want that when the programmer types:  `service.DoSomething(...., typeof(KTM));` the code gives an error on compile.

Thanks

Comment: Why not just make the function inside the `BMW` class and pass the service as parameter into the function?

Comment: Let's start with why `DoSomething` needs this type parameter.  What is it doing with this information?  It's possible that this isn't the correct approach to begin with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using generics for your use case. It would look like:

```
void DoSomething<T>(<some other parameters>) where T: Car {}

service.DoSomething<BMW>(...);
```